# order date query, syntax error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

The following query I want to use to order the dates of order placed by stores. I want to do them in ascending order however when I try to test run this I get the following error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable |
>   ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got
>   'order'

```
$orderSales = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Order")->createQueryBuilder('order');

    $orderSales->orderBy('order.date', 'asc');
    $orderSales = $orderSales->getQuery();
    $orderResult = $orderSales->getResult();
```

I do render orderResult in the .twig template

```
return $this->render('admin/store/sales/adminsales.html.twig', array(
                            'orderResult' =>$orderResult
    ));
```

Comment: As an advice, you should create an indepedant repository method instead of creating your queryBuilder inside Controller.

Comment: Thanks I will change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error when using word `order` in `createQueryBuilder('order')`

Change `order`

**To**

just `o` for example `createQueryBuilder('o')`

**Result:**

```
$orderSales = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Order")->createQueryBuilder('o');

$orderSales->orderBy('o.date', 'asc');
$orderSales = $orderSales->getQuery();
$orderResult = $orderSales->getResult();
```

---

Answer (score 3):

You should declare your QueryBuilder in your Repository such as *(createQueryBuilder accepts argument)* :

```
public function findOrdersByDate()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->orderBy('o.date', 'asc');

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

In your controller :

```
$orderResult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Order")->findOrdersByDate();
```

EDIT : As Imanali Mamadiev has pointed out : replace "order" by just "o" to avoid SQL Keywords conflicts

Answer (score 2):

The method `createQueryBuilder` don't accept arguments, so put your alias in the `select` method as follow:

```
$orderSales = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Order")->createQueryBuilder();

$orderSales->select('order');

$orderSales->orderBy('order.date', 'asc');
$orderSales = $orderSales->getQuery();
$orderResult = $orderSales->getResult();
```

Hope this help